# Can we get factor matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, vector, integer, r-factor

It seems not possible to get matrices of factor in R. Is it true? If yes, why? If not, how should I do?

```
f <- factor(sample(letters[1:5], 20, rep=TRUE), letters[1:5])
m <- matrix(f,4,5)
is.factor(m) # fail.

m <- factor(m,letters[1:5])
is.factor(m) # oh, yes? 
is.matrix(m) # nope. fail. 

dim(f) <- c(4,5) # aha?
is.factor(f) # yes.. 
is.matrix(f) # yes!

# but then I get a strange behavior
cbind(f,f) # is not a factor anymore
head(f,2) # doesn't give the first 2 rows but the first 2 elements of f
# should I worry about it?
```

Comment: Why do you need a matrix of factors? Did you think about using `data.frame` (which supports factors much better) instead of a matrix?

Comment: @nicola I did think about it, yeah. But a `data.frame` really is too much for what I need. Is it not natural to need a matrix of comparable, homogeneous elements?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In this case, it may walk like a duck and even quack like a duck, but `f` from:

```
f <- factor(sample(letters[1:5], 20, rep=TRUE), letters[1:5])
dim(f) <- c(4,5)
```

really isn't a matrix, even though `is.matrix()` claims that it strictly is one. To be a matrix as far as `is.matrix()` is concerned, `f` only needs to be a vector and have a `dim` attribute. By adding the attribute to `f` you pass the test. As you have seen, however, once you start using `f` as a matrix, it quickly loses the features that make it a factor (you end up working with the levels or the dimensions get lost).

There are really only matrices and arrays for the atomic vector types:

1. logical,
2. integer,
3. real,
4. complex,
5. string (or character), and
6. raw

plus, as @hadley reminds me, you can also have list matrices and arrays (by setting the `dim` attribute on a list object. See, for example, the [Matrices & Arrays](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#matrices-and-arrays) section of Hadley's book, *Advanced R*.)

Anything outside those types would be coerced to some lower type via `as.vector()`. This happens in `matrix(f, nrow = 3)` not because `f` is atomic *according to* `is.atomic()` (which returns `TRUE` for `f` because it is internally stored as an integer and `typeof(f)` returns `"integer"`), but because it has a `class` attribute. This sets the `OBJECT` bit on the internal representation of `f` and anything that has a class is supposed to be coerced to one of the atomic types via `as.vector()`:

```
matrix <- function(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
                   dimnames = NULL) {
    if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
        data <- as.vector(data)
....
```

Adding dimensions via `dim<-()` is a quick way to create an array without duplicating the object, but this bypasses some of the checks and balances that R would do if you coerced `f` to a matrix via the other methods

```
matrix(f, nrow = 3) # or
as.matrix(f)
```

This gets found out when you try to use basic functions that work on matrices or use method dispatch. Note that after assigning dimensions to `f`, `f` still is of class `"factor"`:

```
> class(f)
[1] "factor"
```

which explains the `head()` behaviour; you are not getting the `head.matrix` behaviour because `f` is not a matrix, at least as far as the S3 mechanism is concerned:

```
> debug(head.matrix)
> head(f) # we don't enter the debugger
[1] d c a d b d
Levels: a b c d e
> undebug(head.matrix)
```

and the `head.default` method calls `[` for which there is a `factor` method, and hence the observed behaviour:

```
> debugonce(`[.factor`)
> head(f)
debugging in: `[.factor`(x, seq_len(n))
debug: {
    y <- NextMethod("[")
    attr(y, "contrasts") <- attr(x, "contrasts")
    attr(y, "levels") <- attr(x, "levels")
    class(y) <- oldClass(x)
    lev <- levels(x)
    if (drop) 
        factor(y, exclude = if (anyNA(levels(x))) 
            NULL
        else NA)
    else y
}
....
```

The `cbind()` behaviour can be explained from the documented behaviour (from `?cbind`, emphasis mine):

> The functions `cbind` and `rbind` are **S3 generic**, ...
>
> ....
>
> In the default method, all the vectors/matrices must be atomic
>        (see `vector`) or lists.  Expressions are not allowed.  Language
>        objects (such as formulae and calls) and pairlists will be coerced
>        to lists: other objects (such as names and external pointers) will
>        be included as elements in a list result.  **Any classes the inputs
>        might have are discarded (in particular, factors are replaced by
>        their internal codes).**

Again, the fact that `f` is of class `"factor"` is defeating you because the default `cbind` method will get called and it will strip the levels information and return the internal integer codes as you observed.

In many respects, you have to ignore or at least not fully trust what the `is.foo` functions tell you, because they are just using simple tests to say whether something is or is not a `foo` object. `is.matrix()` and `is.atomic()` are clearly wrong when it comes to `f` (with dimensions) *from a particular point of view*. They are also right in terms of their implementation or at least their behaviour can be understood from the implementation; I think `is.atomic(f)` is not correct, but if by *"if is of an atomic type"* R Core mean "type" to be the thing returned by `typeof(f)` then `is.atomic()` is right. A more strict test is `is.vector()`, which `f` fails:

```
> is.vector(f)
[1] FALSE
```

because it has attributes beyond a `names` attribute:

```
> attributes(f)
$levels
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$class
[1] "factor"

$dim
[1] 4 5
```

As to how should you get a factor matrix, well you can't, at least if you want it to retain the factor information (the labels for the levels). One solution would be to use a character matrix, which would retain the labels:

```
> fl <- levels(f)
> fm <- matrix(f, ncol = 5)
> fm
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "c"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "b" 
[2,] "d"  "b"  "d"  "b"  "a" 
[3,] "e"  "e"  "e"  "c"  "e" 
[4,] "a"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "e"
```

and we store the levels of `f` for future use incase we lose some elements of the matrix along the way.

Or work with the internal integer representation:

```
> (fm2 <- matrix(unclass(f), ncol = 5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    1    1    3    2
[2,]    4    2    4    2    1
[3,]    5    5    5    3    5
[4,]    1    2    2    1    5
```

and you can always get back to the levels/labels again via:

```
> fm2[] <- fl[fm2]
> fm2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "c"  "a"  "a"  "c"  "b" 
[2,] "d"  "b"  "d"  "b"  "a" 
[3,] "e"  "e"  "e"  "c"  "e" 
[4,] "a"  "b"  "b"  "a"  "e"
```

Using a data frame would seem to be not ideal for this as each component of the data frame would be treated as a separate factor whereas you seem to want to treat the array as a single factor with one set of levels.

If you really wanted to do what you want, which is have a factor matrix, you would most likely need to create your own S3 class to do this, plus all the methods to go with it. For example, you might store the factor matrix as a character matrix but with class `"factorMatrix"`, where you stored the levels alongside the factor matrix as an extra attribute say. Then you would need to write `[.factorMatrix`, which would grab the levels, then use the default `[` method on the matrix, and then add the levels attribute back on again. You could write `cbind`and `head` methods as well. The list of required method would grow quickly however, but a simple implementation may suit and if you make your objects have class `c("factorMatrix", "matrix")` (i.e inherit from the `"matrix"` class), you'll pick up all the properties/methods of the `"matrix"` class (which will drop the levels and other attributes) so you can at least work with the objects and see where you need to add new methods to fill out the behaviour of the class.

Comment: Great explanation `+1`, but disagree that the "factor" matrix is not a matrix.  Rather, the failures for OP are an artifact of the inconsistent treatment of implicit classes in S3 dispatch.  If R treated our factor matrix as class `c("factor", "matrix", "integer")` then most functions would work fine.  I think failure to do so is a (small) design flaw in R.

Comment: Although your point about attribute discarding functions (`rbind`, etc.) still stands.

Comment: You can always mash the result of a function into a matrixy factor thing: `structure(cbind(f,f),levels=levels(f),class=class(f))` - basically restoring the attributes that the `cbind` method took off. #hackhack

Comment: @BrodieG I would add that *"it depends what you by **is a matrix**" when it comes to whether the `f`-matrix is a matrix or not. From the viewpoint of `is.matrix` it clearly is. From the point of view of the S3 class system, it isn't (it is not of class `"matrix"` nor does it inherit from it). From the point of view of what the docs define a matrix to be, if also isn't a matrix as `f` is not an atomic vector. That last point is perhaps pertinent; that you can end up with an object that looks like a matrix is a quirk, which soon gets rectified. And yes, R could be improved if R Core wanted too.

Comment: @Spacedman, re: your comment in R chat, you can `fop=function(f)
  function(x, ...)
    structure(f(unclass(x), ...),levels=levels(x),class=class(x))`.  Still need to account for factors with mixed levels though.

Comment: This just amazes me. `Feels like the learning curve for R never stops climbing to the skies! Many thanks for this pretty complete explanation. I'll go for an integer matrix then, with a character vector storing my levels (this is what I actually did), since it'd be too much work creating a new class and supporting it for my limited knowledge of R. I hope this thread'll be updated if ever R started featuring a broader factor support. Thank you guys anyway ;)

Comment: Lists can also be matrices

Comment: I think it would be better to work with a character matrix since there's less chance of accidentally treating the values like numbers. There's little memory overhead to using strings instead of integers because of the global string pool.

Comment: @BrodieG for there to be such a thing as a factor-matrix, S3 would need to support multiple inheritance, which it does not. (Not that "matrix" is really well defined in the S3 system, being mostly an implicit class)

Comment: @hadley, I'm not sure multiple inheritance is needed here.  Consider this example from `ts`: `z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)`.  Both a time series and a matrix (though the matrix is defined explicitly).  Simple linear inheritance is fine.  In fact, we can do stuff like `class(f)<-c("factor", "matrix")` and all of a sudden `head(f)` actually works.

Comment: @BrodieG I think you might be able to make it work, but it's going to fundamentally be a kludge. Matrix isn't even really an S3 class

Comment: @hadley, agree, though I do think it should be since it is treated as such (i.e. there are a lot of `.matrix` methods).  There is this unfortunate discrepancy that when there is no class, then S3 dispatches on Matrix, but when there is one, the implicit class is ignored.  There is really no reason why the implicit classes shouldn't be dispatched on when there are explicit classes (other than that isn't how R is coded).

Comment: @hadley Thanks; knew I would miss one. I've added a note to this effect with a link to the relevant section of Advanced R where this is shown.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately factor support is not completely universal in R, so many R functions default to treating factors as their internal storage type, which is `integer`:

```
> typeof(factor(letters[1:3]))
[1] "integer
```

This is what happens with `matrix`, `cbind`.  They don't know how to handle factors, but they do know what to do with integers, so they treat your factor like an integer.  `head` is actually the opposite.  It does know how to handle a factor, but it never bothers to check that your factor is also a matrix so just treats it like a normal dimensionless factor vector.

Your best bet to operate as if you had factors with your matrix is to coerce it to character.  Once you are done with your operations, you can restore it back to factor form.  You could also do this with the integer form, but then you risk weird stuff (you could for example do matrix multiplication on an integer matrix, but that makes no sense for factors).

Note that if you add class "matrix" to your factor some (but not all) things start working:

```
f <- factor(letters[1:9])
dim(f) <- c(3, 3)
class(f) <- c("factor", "matrix")
head(f, 2)
```

Produces:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] a    d    g   
[2,] b    e    h   
Levels: a b c d e f g h i
```

This doesn't fix `rbind`, etc.

Comment: Let's go for the integer matrix then, since I feel it's *heavy* to work with characters when all I need is 5 or 10 levels.. and try not to make dummy operations with my matrix ;)

Comment: @lago-lito, as per Hadley's comment, characters don't actually take up much room at all since the actual character strings are only stored once in memory.  Also, note update to my answer

Comment: Oh really? Where should I read further about the way matrices are stored in memory? I must admit that it does feel weird thinking of a matrix of integer as light as a matrix of strings..

Comment: @lago-lito, see the note in `?factor` for the cost of character vectors.  Matrices are just stored as vectors with a `dim` attribute, so the only thing that really matters is how the underlying vector is stored.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've also just found the function `utils::object.size` that can help me measuring the actual weight of my matrices, `lot of fun ;)