# Extracting a specific type columns and specific named columns from a data frame-R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Let I have a data frame where some colums rae factor type and there is column named "index" which is not a column. I want to extract columns

- which are factor tyepe and
- the "index" column.

For example let

```
df<-data.frame(a=runif(10),b=as.factor(sample(10)),index=as.numeri(1:10))
```

So df is:

```
         a  b index
0.16187501  5     1
0.75214741  8     2
0.08741729  3     3
0.58871514  2     4
0.18464752  9     5
0.98392420  1     6
0.73771960 10     7
0.97141474  6     8
0.15768011  7     9
0.10171931  4    10
```

Desired output is(let it be a data frame called df1)

df1:

```
   b index
   5     1
   8     2
   3     3
   2     4
   9     5
   1     6
  10     7
   6     8
   7     9
   4    10
```

which consist the factor column and the column named "index".

I use such a code

```
  vars<-apply(df,2,function(x) {(is.factor(x)) || (names(x)=="index")})

  df1<-df[,vars]
```

However, this code does not work. How can I return df1 using apply types function in R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
df[ , sapply(df, is.factor) | grepl("index", names(df))]
```

I think two things went wrong with your method: First, `apply` converts the data frame to a matrix, which doesn't store values as factors (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724756/496488) for more on this). Also, in a matrix, every value has to be of the same mode (character, numeric, etc.). In this case, everything gets coerced to character, so there's no factor to find.

Second, the column name isn't accessible within `apply` (AFAIK), so `names(x)` returns `NULL` and `names(x)=="index"` returns `logical(0)`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and detailed explanation. It was very useful for me. Thansk again.