# Convert data frame columns to factor with indexing

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, types

I have some results that I put in a data frame. I have some factor columns and many numeric columns. I can easily convert the numeric columns to numeric with indexing, as per the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame) question.

```
#create example data
df = data.frame(replicate(1000,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df$X1 = LETTERS[df$X1]
df$X2 = LETTERS[df$X2]
df$X3 = LETTERS[df$X3]
df[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], function(x) ifelse(runif(length(x)) < 0.1, NA, x))

#find columns that are factors
factornames = c("X1", "X2", "X3")
factorfilt = names(df) %in% factornames

#convert non-factor columns to numeric
df[, !factorfilt] = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[, !factorfilt])))
```

But when I want to do the same for my factor columns, I cant get the same indexing to work:

```
#convert factor columns to factor
df[, factorfilt] = as.factor(as.character(unlist(df[, factorfilt])))
class(df$X1)

[1] "character"

df[, factorfilt] = as.factor(as.character(df[, factorfilt]))
class(df$X1)

[1] "character"

df[, factorfilt] = as.factor(unlist(df[, factorfilt]))
class(df$X1)

[1] "character"

df[, factorfilt] = as.factor(df[, factorfilt]) 

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

All of these return `"character"` if I call `class(df$X1)`, while if I run `df$X1= as.factor(df$X1)` it returns `"factor"`.

Why does indexing this way not work when I call `as.factor`, but does if I call `as.numeric`?

Comment: The `as.factor` or `as.character` etc works on a `vector` and not on `data.frame`.  You need to loop through the columns and then do `factor`

Comment: Isnt that why `unlist` is in there?

Comment: Following akrun's comment, use `lapply` to run through the selected columns and perform the coercion: `df[, factorfilt] <- lapply(df[, factorfilt],  as.factor)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this with indexing, since it also works for `as.numeric`

Comment: `numeric` is an atomic data type, while factor is a special data type that maps labels to integers and has it's own class. A `data.frame` has its own class, an attempt to reassign the values in `as.factor(unlist(df[, factorfilt]))` (which is a factor) into multiple columns of the data.frame, cause the function to convert the unlisted vector to character before reassignment. The function involved is pretty complicated, type `\`[<-.data.frame\`` to take a look. The line that strips the factor class and converts to character may be `value <- matrix(value, n, p)`, since a matrix has its own class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so clearly. So this is just not possible? Would be a good answer.

Comment: In general, `mutate_if` is a great way to convert all columns of one type to another.

Comment: Yes that looks very convenient. I also found that in the bottom answer to the question below. It just gets so kungfoosing to use different functions for the same operation, thats why I wanted to do it the same way as advised for the numeric columns. I will make a comment to the answer that I lnked to at the top of my post and say that the advised solution is not generally applicable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637360/convert-all-data-frame-character-columns-to-factors

Comment: A pretty detailed response on trying to have factor matrices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723059/can-we-get-factor-matrices-in-r. From that answer, when you use `matrix(...)` it uses `as.vector()` on the data before building the matrix. This is what converts factors to characters (try `class(as.vector(factor(c(1,2,3))))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should observe some behavioral aspects of what you are doing.  Defining your data as you did:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(1000,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df$X1 = LETTERS[df$X1]
df$X2 = LETTERS[df$X2]
df$X3 = LETTERS[df$X3]
df[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], function(x) ifelse(runif(length(x)) < 0.1, NA, x))

factornames = c("X1", "X2", "X3")
factorfilt = names(df) %in% factornames
df[, !factorfilt] = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[, !factorfilt])))
```

Now let's take a look at the result of making the `X1`, `X2`, and `X3` factors as you did, but let's not reassign it yet.

```
test <- as.factor(as.character(df[, factorfilt]))
class(test) # "factor"
length(test) # 3
```

The important thing to notice here is that `test` *is not a data frame*. It's a vector, that you are attempting to save over three columns of a data frame.  I think we should question the wisdom of converting a data frame to a vector to store in a data frame.

Then consider your second assignment:

```
test2 <- as.factor(as.character(unlist(df[, factorfilt])))
class(test2) # factor
length(test2) # 3000
```

Again, it's a factor, but it has a completely different length than `test`.  R is being kind by letting you reassign this back into `df` at all, and is only doing so because it recognizes that it can reconcile the dimensions.  But when you try to push the factors into `X1`, `X2`, and `X3`, there's a big question about what to do with the factor levels.  Should all three variables have the same levels?  Should each variable only have the levels present within itself?  Instead of attempting to declare what the "appropriate" choice is, R just ignores it and converts it back to a character for you to deal with on your own.

The fact that manipulating columns this way has the potential to change classes unexpectedly is a good reason not to do it.  This is evident in your assignment of the `NA`s.  Let's revisit:

```
df = data.frame(replicate(1000,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df$X1 = LETTERS[df$X1]
df$X2 = LETTERS[df$X2]
df$X3 = LETTERS[df$X3]
```

At this point, `X4` through `X1000` are all `integer` class columns.  When you run

```
df[-1] <- sapply(df[-1], function(x) ifelse(runif(length(x)) < 0.1, NA, x))
```

They are all now `character`s, and you proceed to convert them to `numeric`. They aren't even their original class anymore.

If, instead, we use `lapply`

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) ifelse(runif(length(x)) < 0.1, NA, x))
```

the original classes are preserved and there's no need to convert them back to a numeric class.  Similarly, we can readily convert `X1` through `X3` to factors with

```
df[, factorfilt] <- lapply(df[, factorfilt], as.factor)
```

As a general rule, it is better to manipulate the data in columns as distinct columns.  Once you begin assigning a single vector over multiple columns, you enter a dark world of mischief.

Comment: Hmm I was not aware of those things at all, thanks. Reading about `sapply` and `lapply` it seems they are the same though?

Comment: There's a difference in what they return.  `sapply` returns either a vector or a matrix (in this particular case, I think it's a really long vector).  `lapply` returns a list, which will keep the columns of your data frame properly partitioned.