# Converting dataframe with factors to data matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, r-factor

I have a data frame like so in R:

```
> race <- factor(c(0,1,0,1,1))
> income <- factor(c(1,1,1,0,0))
> df <- data.frame(race, income)
> df
  race income
1    0      1
2    1      1
3    0      1
4    1      0
5    1      0
```

I want to convert it to a data matrix

When i do so i get this where my values get added by 1:

```
t <- data.matrix(df)
> t
     race income
[1,]    1      2
[2,]    2      2
[3,]    1      2
[4,]    2      1
[5,]    2      1
```

Why does this happen and how do i ensure the values of the data matrix are the same as the data frame?

Comment: Please understand that `matrix` can hold only a single class and here, the factor is coerced to its integer storage mode.  You may need to reconvert to `integer` i.e `data.matrix(type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE))`

Comment: You basically [can't have factors in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723059/903061). Why do you want them? If you explain the context, we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I don't need them as factors they are fine as integers. How can I change dynamically all factor columns to integer columns. I've tried this `df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(where(is.factor), numeric))` but i'm getting an invalid 'length' argument.

Comment: `numeric` isn't a function, use `mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.integer))`. Or `mutate(across(where(is.factor), \(x) as.integer(x) - 1))` if you want to subtract 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 1 from the matrix to make the values align.

```r
t <- data.matrix(df)
t - 1
#>      race income
#> [1,]    0      1
#> [2,]    1      1
#> [3,]    0      1
#> [4,]    1      0
#> [5,]    1      0
```

Or you can first convert to `character` and then to a `matrix`.

```r
lapply(df, as.character) |> 
  lapply(as.numeric) |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  as.matrix()
#>      race income
#> [1,]    0      1
#> [2,]    1      1
#> [3,]    0      1
#> [4,]    1      0
#> [5,]    1      0
```

Edit: Just saw you comment about only changing `factor` vars to `numeric`. In that
case try this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), 
                \(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))) |> 
  as.matrix()
#>      race income
#> [1,]    0      1
#> [2,]    1      1
#> [3,]    0      1
#> [4,]    1      0
#> [5,]    1      0
```

Some background: When converting a `factor` to `numeric` R will conserve the order of the
factor levels by counting up starting with `1`, not `0`.

```r
factor("A") |> as.numeric()
#> [1] 1
factor(0) |> as.numeric()
#> [1] 1
factor(c(1,3,7)) |> as.numeric()
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

If your factor levels are numbers, you can conserve the exact values by
converting to `character` first.

```r
factor(0) |> as.character() |> as.numeric()
#> [1] 0
factor(c(1,3,7)) |> as.character() |> as.numeric()
#> [1] 1 3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try `class<-` + `as.matrix` like below

```
> `class<-`(as.matrix(df),"numeric")
     race income
[1,]    0      1
[2,]    1      1
[3,]    0      1
[4,]    1      0
[5,]    1      0
```