# Coerce factor matrix into a data.frame

Tags: r

I am a bit confused about an object I am working with:

```
a <-
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Label = c("FALSE", "TRUE"
), class = "factor")
```

```
> a
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

I tried to coerce it into a `data.frame`, but the result wasn't what I expected:

```
> as.data.frame(a)
     a.1   a.2   a.3
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE FALSE
6  FALSE FALSE FALSE
7   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
9   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
10  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
11  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
12  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
13  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
14  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
15  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
16  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
17  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
18  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
Warning message:
In format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x,  :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
```

I was expecting it to work just like with any other matrix, but I am confused about why this wouldn't work.

What is going on? And is there a "clean" way to coerce it?

Thank you

Comment: Try `as.data.frame.matrix(a)`

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible, thank you! I am still confused as to why `class(a)` is `factor` in the first place and it's taking precedence over `matrix`...

Comment: This [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724756/16647496) might be relevant

Comment: You have a very odd data format, and if you can manage to get the columns to be `logical` and not `factor`, that will save you some time

Comment: @Maël indeed, for posterity this is the output of  data extracted using `rhdf5`  (otype `H5I_DATASET`, dclass `ENUM`)

Comment: Just following up on this: the more I work with this data, the weirder `as.data.frame.matrix()` becomes, since it's also coercing `factor` into `logical` according to the factor label and not the underlying value... which is what I want, but not what I would expect it!